# Recursive tree insertion only creates root node

Tags: python, data-structures, tree

My function is given a vector. It gets the maximum value from it and creates a root node for it. It then divides the vector in two at the index of this highest value (excluding that value itself). The left side of the vector should then be used recursively to set the root's left child. The same should happen at the right.

But my code is only filling in the root node. Why?

```
import numpy as np

class Node:
    def __init__(self, information):
        self.information = information
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Max_Tree:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None

    def insert(self, array):
        if len(array) == 0:
            return 0
        max_value_index = np.argmax(array)
        self.root = Node(array[max_value_index])
        array_left = array[0: max_value_index]
        array_right = array[max_value_index + 1:]
        self._insert(array_left, self.root.left)
        self._insert(array_right, self.root.right)

    def _insert(self, array, node):
        if len(array) == 0:
            return 0
        max_value_index = np.argmax(array)
        node = Node(array[max_value_index])
        array_left = array[0: max_value_index]
        array_right = array[max_value_index + 1:]
        self._insert(array_left, node.left)
        self._insert(array_right, node.right)
```

Example run:

```
array = np.array([2, 42, 17, 13, 21, 50, 32, 9, 14])
max_tree = Max_Tree()
max_tree.insert(array)
print(max_tree.root.information)  # OK
print(max_tree.root.left)  # None ???? Why ???
```

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.
Your posted code does nothing but define two classes and quit without executing anything.

Comment: You pass in a reference of the left and right nodes `self._insert(array_left, node.left)`, but then when that function runs, it simply creates a new `node` variable. At no point in your code do actually assign a value to `node.left` or `node.right` of the original root.

Comment: @Mark How can I assign? I did not understand.

Comment: @DavidSousa at some point you need to have code that assigns to `.right` and `.left`' properties. That would look like `node.right = something`. It *doesn't* works to send a reference through a function like `self._insert(array_left, node.left)` <-- `node.left` here is just None.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when you call `self._insert`, the second argument is *always* `None`. In Python arguments are passed by value, so in this case there is just the value `None`... there is no way the function is going to update the variable of the caller: it has its own parameter variable, and only that variable will get the reference to the new Node that it creates. But that reference is lost when the function returns. So all that work is done for nothing.

Instead, design your `self._insert` function so that it will not take that second argument, but will *return* the `Node` it creates for the given array. Then it is the caller's responsibility to assign that returned `Node` instance to whatever property (`left`, `right`, `root`, ...).

Here is how `self._insert` should be adapted:

```
def _insert(self, array):
    if len(array) == 0:
        return  # Return None!

    max_value_index = np.argmax(array)
    node = Node(array[max_value_index])
    array_left = array[0: max_value_index]
    array_right = array[max_value_index + 1:]

    node.left = self._insert(array_left)  # Assign the returned Node instance (or None)
    node.right = self._insert(array_right)  # Same priniciple

    return node  # Return the new Node with all its descendants
```

Once you have this, the main `self.insert` function does not have to repeat any of this code. It can just delegate the call to `self._insert` and assign the result to the root:

```
def insert(self, array):
    self.root = self._insert(array)
```

Comment: Now I see the error. Thank you very much.